# FAQ index links

Tags: discussion, meta-faq

I just made some updates to https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1646/faq-index-for-programmers-se, adding some missing [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) questions, mostly.

I think that each of the questions in [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) should have a link back to the index, similar to the links on MSE ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8010/how-can-i-get-answers-fast)) and SO ([example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271542/why-wont-the-system-allow-me-to-ask-questions-for-several-days)).

I think this link should take the form:

> <sub>`[Return to FAQ index](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1646)`</sub>

At the bottom of the question post for each FAQ entry.

However, I don't have edit privileges here and suggested edits are not allowed on [faq](/questions/tagged/faq). Presuming there are no objections to adding a FAQ index backlink to each entry, does somebody want to make these edits?

If these changes are made, a note should probably be added to the end of the "How can a question be added to this FAQ" section at https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1647/121251 as well.

Comment: Something to consider instead is moving the faq index from a question and answer (which can only be modified by 2k+, and then does so without any other checks) into the faq tag itself via the wiki: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/tags/faq/info .  Here, anyone can modify it, though it still goes through the suggested edit review until 20k (for that extra check).